# Getting stuck at "Hold tight" screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I've followed the tutorials for setting up tango with unity and for a simple test app (https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-simple-ar) but i can't get it to build on my phone (Motorola moto G 2nd edition). When i "build and run" I only get the "hold tight" screen which seems to take forever and nothing else happens. Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: There are no telepaths here. [MCVE]

Comment: I'm sorry if this seems like a badly formed question or smth, but I just thought that maybe there's some obvious thing that might cause this, or atleast somebody could tell me what should I try looking into? I provided the link to the tutorial that i followed, theres no code that i could add in the question what I did is: Configure the Tango Manager (followed the steps provided there), added Tango Camera and the sphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your device (Motorola moto G 2nd edition) is not prepared for Tango to build a app with tango you need a device that support Tango

https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/java/

Note: The Android emulator cannot be used for this project or any other project that uses the Tango API. You must have a Tango device.

Comment: Thanks!
I totally missed that :<